# Node.JS Google Calendar Promise return of the list of events

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, promise, async-await

I currently have a NodeJS application where I want to grab a list of events and after that make a data structure with it, but my promise is not waiting for the return of the func, here's the code:

This should wait for the getEvents return and then log the value received

```
console.log("Schedule");
scheduler.getEvents(searchRange)
    .then((value) => {
        console.log("value");
        console.log(value);
    });
```

This is the getEvents function that uses the calendar api to get the list of the events on the client calendar, it should return na, but it actually returns before the calendar api return the list.

```
async function getEvents(searchRange) {
let na = [];

calendarAPI.listEventsIntervalAPI(searchRange.startDate, searchRange.endDate, (events) => {
    events.forEach((event) => {
        na.push({
            start: moment(event.start.timeDate),
            end: moment(event.end.timeDate)
        });
    });
    return na;
});
}
```

And then finally the API call that gets the calendar events list:

```
async function listEventsIntervalAPI(dI, dE, callback) {
let dateInitial = moment(dI).toDate();
let dateEnd = moment(dE).toDate();

const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3' });
calendar.events.list({
    auth: oauth2Client,
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: dateInitial.toISOString(),
    timeMax: dateEnd.toISOString(),
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
}, (err, { data } = {}) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    }

    const events = data.items;
    if (events.length) {
        callback(events);
    } else {
        console.log('No upcoming events found.');
        callback(events);
    }
});
}
```

My question is why the return is not properly being waited? I know the calendar.list isn't async but is there a way for me to wait for this return and actually do this syncronously? I tried inserting the callback in the func call or just turning into async and using await but none worked.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the way you're calling the getEvents method in that first snippet of code suggests you are expecting a Promise to be returned from getEvents. But you're actually not really returning anything. I don't know the Google calendar API very well, and `listEventsIntervalAPI` may very well return a Promise, but you aren't returning that. If you're trying to return just the populated `na` array, the issue is you've got `return na;` in the body of the callback method, which means the context of that return statement is *for that* callback method, not for the getEvents method itself.

There are a number of ways to solve this, but a good way keeping in line with what you already have is to return a Promise from the getEvents function itself. It might look like this:

```
async function getEvents(searchRange) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        calendarAPI.listEventsIntervalAPI(searchRange.startDate, searchRange.endDate, (events) => {
            if (!events) {
                reject("No events returned");
            }

            let na = [];
            events.forEach((event) => {
                na.push({
                    start: moment(event.start.timeDate),
                    end: moment(event.end.timeDate)
                });
            });
            resolve(na);
        });
    });
}
```

You'll want to call `reject()` within the Promise for when you have an error you want handled, and `resolve()` for otherwise.

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Comment: This answer perfectly! Thanks a bunch.
Just a question, the Promise return in the way you put it work independent if the functions inside it are async or not?

Comment: Yeah, so Promises are designed specifically to encapsulate work that is asynchronous, but you could technically put anything you want in a promise, so long as you fulfill the resolve/reject contract appropriately